# How to synchronize methods in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

i have some small problem.
I hava some class **Processor** and **Process**. **Process** class have only name and value
**Processor** must calculate this value and display it. In turn, **Processor** implement Runnable interface
But i have a trouble. When I set process to my Processor, it begin to calculate value, but i want to start another thread with different value of process, and this value set to first thread too.
Here is code

```
    package ua.edu.lp.controller;

import java.util.Random;

import ua.edu.lp.controller.processors.FirstProcessor;
import ua.edu.lp.controller.processors.MyBaseProcessor;
import ua.edu.lp.model.MyProcess;
import ua.edu.lp.model.Queue;

public class Computer {

    private Queue<MyProcess> queue;

    public void run() {
        MyBaseProcessor myBaseProcessor = new FirstProcessor();
        generateQueue();

        for (int i = 0; i < queue.getQueue().size(); i++) {
            MyProcess process = queue.get(i);
            myBaseProcessor.setProcess(process);
            Thread thread = new Thread(myBaseProcessor);
             thread.start();
        }
    }

    private void generateQueue() {
        queue = new Queue<MyProcess>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            String name = "Process[" + (i + 1) + "]";
            MyProcess myProcess = new MyProcess(name,
                    new Random().nextInt(10) + 1);
            queue.add(myProcess);
            System.out.println(myProcess.getName() + "\t"
                    + myProcess.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

BaseProcessor

```
package ua.edu.lp.controller.processors;

import ua.edu.lp.model.MyProcess;

public abstract class MyBaseProcessor implements Runnable {

    protected MyProcess myProcess;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (myProcess) {
            calculateValue();
        }
    }

    protected abstract void calculateValue();

    public synchronized MyProcess getProcess() {
        return myProcess;
    }

    public synchronized void setProcess(MyProcess myProcess) {
        synchronized (myProcess) {
            this.myProcess = myProcess;
        }

    }

}
```

And FirstProcessor

```
package ua.edu.lp.controller.processors;

public class FirstProcessor extends MyBaseProcessor {

    @Override
    protected synchronized void calculateValue() {
        System.out.println("First processor is working...");
        int value = this.myProcess.getValue();
        int result = (int) Math.pow(value, 2);
        System.out.println("Pow of " + value + " = " + result);
        System.out.println("First processor is free");
    }

}
```

All project you can download from http://www.sendspace.com/file/5rlmkx

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not certain I understand what this is suppose to do.  What is the intended result ?  is this for a homework ? if so you should tag it as such to maximize your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: The `ua.edu` packages suggest its `[homework]` ;)

Comment: I'll try to study multithreading in Java, so i take task in university

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make Processor stateless - remove field process and do something like this:

```
final Processor processor = new Processor();

processor.process(new Process(...));

public void process( final Process process ) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        //do somethig with process
        }).run();
}
```

NOTE: Processor must do only common task - to run process, and process implement business logic and only process aware of calculations you've done.

Comment: Ok, I think i understand my mistake. You mean that threare few processes, flow through the one Processor. Am I understand you exactly?

Comment: Yes, processor has to do common task (run processes), and process has to do specific task (run calculations).

Answer (score 1):

All your task are independant so you shouldn't need synchronized anywhere. However YOu are sharing a BaseProcessor object which while synchronized, is not synchronized for the life of the processing.

You only need synchronized to process shared data where one thread can modify that data after the threads have started.

BTW: I would use an ExecutorService as this wraps the Queues and Thread pools in one class.

I assume your Queue is thread safe because not all Queues are in Java. It could be a problem if it wasn't.

---

This program does the same thing, however its simpelr and thread safe.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    final String name = "Process[" + (i + 1) + "]";
    final int value = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
    service.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("First processor is working...");
            int result = (int) Math.pow(value, 2);
            System.out.println("Pow of " + value + " = " + result);
            System.out.println("First processor is free");
        }
    });
    System.out.println(name + "\t" + value);
}
service.shutdown();
```

Comment: Yes, it's my own Queue class. It contains only List.

Comment: How i can do it? Could you help me, please?

Comment: But, in every step of loop, you create new Runnable (in my case Processor), but I have fixed count of processors.

Comment: The number of Runnable is fixed to 10. You create a MyProcess for each task.  I used an anonymous class, but using a named class might be clearer (as you have done).

Comment: If i modified my app, and create on every step of loop new instance of FirstProcessor, it works exactly, but there is problem again ) One Processor!

Answer (score 1):

synchronized (myProcess)

will only set a MUTEX for the myProcess object. Synchronization between different MyBaseProcessor objects will only work, if both objects point to the the same myProcess object.

I don't know what the concrete requirements are, but it looks correct for me=> Not more than one processor whould work on a single process?

A bit confusing for me is why you are also synchronizing in the setterMethod setProcess(..) with the target field. This does not have any effect.

Maybe you didn't understand that the synchronization will be done with the object and not the type?

BR - Michael

Comment: I think it will set one process, and when thread will complete it will be set new Process to another thread. Yes you quite right, one processor may process only one Process, in the future I'll need to make SecondProcessor with another logic, and every of processors will process only one Process!